# How to hide Site Actions tab, but show Sign In link in a different place

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new on SharePoint 2010 and trying to make basic web sites. 
First, created a new site. Using domain authantication. I've done to hide Site Actions tab. Surrounded the tags with

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID = "spstcSiteActions" runat = "server" PermissionsString = "ManageWeb">
```

When you do this, end-user cant see Site Actions ribbon, but cant see Sign In link too :)
I want to make Site Actions invisible, but Sign In link visible. When the user clicks then link, he can see Site Actions ribbon if authentication is success. My question is How to hide Site Actions tab, but show Sign In link in same tab or at different place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried this on SharePoint 2010 but might know a workaround. You could try putting a link on your masterpage that points to /_layouts/authenticate.aspx . Once the user clicks on the url, they will be authenticated and brought back. Then the trimmed control can show the site actions menu depending on permissions.

You'll need a trimmed control around the login link in order to hide it when the user is authenticated.

Comment: I've found a tag in Site Actions ribbon which contains Sign In link. The tag src is redirected to ~/_catalogs/Welcome.ascx. When you move this tag anywhere in your master page, it works aswell. But there should be a custom authenticate link like your answer. I will try it tomorrow, cuz left the office. Thanks for your advice. I'll reply this answer tomorrow again. Farewell.

Comment: Hello Zeb. I've tried your suggestion. First, it works for authenticate me to web site, but there should be a something like default Sign In link, when you Signed In your name should appear on the link, and user menu (My Settings, Sign Out,Personalize This Page) should be displayed to authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into what CustomActions are available to you.  I've used custom actions in SP2007 to add items to the site actions menu.  You might be able to leverage something something similar to hide an item.

Here's a related article:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418728(office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418728%28office.12%29.aspx)